# What to add to a Flappy Bird JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I have a 200 line fully functional flappy bird code but I was told it's suppose to be 250 lines. I don't know what more I can add to the js of the game to improve it and make it longer. I was told I can maybe add a pause button but I only know how to do it through css and not through JS. any suggestions? I also thought about lowering the restart button under the line of the score and speed and centering it but it didn't work for me.

```js
var bird;
var pole1;
var pole2;
var scoreSpan;
var speedSpan;
var highSpan;
var speed;
var score;
var high;
var flapping;
var playing;
var scoreUpdated;
var gameArea;
var restartBtn;
var containerWidth;
var containerHeight;

function load() {
    high = 0;
    bird = document.getElementById("bird")
    poles = document.querySelectorAll(".pole")
    pole1 = document.getElementById("pole-1")
    pole2 = document.getElementById("pole-2")
    scoreSpan = document.getElementById("score")
    speedSpan = document.getElementById("speed")
    highSpan = document.getElementById("high")
    gameArea = document.getElementById("game-area");
    restartBtn = document.getElementById("restart-btn");
    containerWidth = gameArea.clientWidth;
    containerHeight = gameArea.clientHeight;

    gameArea.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        if (playing) {
            flapping = true;
        }
    });

    gameArea.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        if (playing) {
            flapping = false;
        }
    });
}
function restart() {
    restartBtn.removeEventListener('click', restart);
    if (score >= high) {
        high = score;
    }
    speed = 2;
    score = 0;
    scoreUpdated = false;
    flapping = false;
    playing = true;
    speedSpan.textContent = speed;
    scoreSpan.textContent = score;
    highSpan.textContent = high;
    poles.forEach((pole) => {
        pole.style.right = 0;
    });
    bird.style.top = 20 + "%";
    gameLoop();
}

function update() {

    var polesCurrentPos = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(poles[0]).getPropertyValue("right"));

    if (polesCurrentPos > containerWidth * 0.85) {
        if (!scoreUpdated) {
            score += 1;
            scoreUpdated = true;
        }
        scoreSpan.textContent = score;
        if (score >= high) {
            high = score;
            highSpan.textContent = high;
        }
    }

    if (polesCurrentPos > containerWidth) {

        var newHeight = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
        pole1.style.height = 100 + newHeight + "px";
        pole2.style.height = 100 - newHeight + "px";

        polesCurrentPos = 0;

        speed += 0.25;
        speedSpan.textContent = parseInt(speed);
        scoreUpdated = false;
    }

    poles.forEach((pole) => {
        pole.style.right = polesCurrentPos + speed + "px";
    });

    let birdTop = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(bird).getPropertyValue("top"));
    if (flapping) {
        bird.style.top = birdTop + -2 + "px";
    } else if (birdTop < containerHeight - bird.clientHeight) {
        bird.style.top = birdTop + 2 + "px";
    }

    if (collision(bird, pole1) || collision(bird, pole2) || birdTop <= 0 || birdTop > containerHeight - bird.clientHeight) {
        gameOver();
    }
}

function gameOver() {
    window.console.log("Game Over!:(");
    playing = false;
    restartBtn.addEventListener('click', restart);
}

function gameLoop() {
    update();
    if (playing) {
        requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }
}

function collision(gameDiv1, gameDiv2) {
    let left1 = gameDiv1.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let top1 = gameDiv1.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let height1 = gameDiv1.clientHeight;
    let width1 = gameDiv1.clientWidth;

    let bottom1 = top1 + height1;
    let right1 = left1 + width1;
    let left2 = gameDiv2.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let top2 = gameDiv2.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let height2 = gameDiv2.clientHeight;
    let width2 = gameDiv2.clientWidth;
    let bottom2 = top2 + height2;
    let right2 = left2 + width2;

    if (bottom1 < top2 || top1 > bottom2 || right1 < left2 || left1 > right2)
        return false;
    return true;
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    var key = e.key;
    if (key === " " && playing) {
        flapping = true;
    }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var key = e.key;
    if (key === " " && playing) {
        flapping = false;
    }
});
var myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement("div"),
    game: document.getElementById("game"),
    gamearea: document.createElement("div"),
    gameinfo: document.createElement("div"),
    bird: document.createElement("div"),
    pole1: document.createElement("div"),
    pole2: document.createElement("div"),
    score: document.createElement("p"),
    scores: document.createElement("span"),
    speed: document.createElement("p"),
    speeds: document.createElement("span"),
    high: document.createElement("p"),
    highs: document.createElement("span"),
    restart: document.createElement("button"),
    start: function () {
        this.canvas.style = "font-family: David, cursive, sans-serif;text-align: center;";
        this.canvas.width = 504;
        this.canvas.height = 341;
        this.game.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.gamearea.style = "margin: auto;position: relative;width: 400px;height: 300px;border: 2px solid green;background-color: deepskyblue;overflow: hidden;";
        this.gamearea.id = "game-area";
        this.canvas.appendChild(this.gamearea);
        this.gameinfo.style = "margin: 5px;font-size: 18px;";
        this.gameinfo.id = "game-info";
        this.canvas.appendChild(this.gameinfo);
        this.bird.style = "position: absolute;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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');height: 27px;width: 42px;background-size: contain;background-repeat: no-repeat;top: 20%;left: 15%;";
        this.bird.id = "bird";
        this.gamearea.appendChild(this.bird);
        this.pole1.style = "position: absolute;height: 100px;width: 30px;background-color: green;right: 0px;top: 0;";
        this.pole1.id = "pole-1";
        this.pole1.className = "pole";
        this.gamearea.appendChild(this.pole1);
        this.pole2.style = "position: absolute;height: 100px;width: 30px;background-color: green;right: 0px; bottom: 0;";
        this.pole2.id = "pole-2";
        this.pole2.className = "pole";
        this.gamearea.appendChild(this.pole2);
        this.restart.id = "restart-btn";
        this.restart.style = "padding: 5px 10px;background-color: green;color: white;font-size: 18px;border: none;cursor: pointer;outline: none;";
        var restartbtn = document.createTextNode("Restart");
        this.restart.appendChild(restartbtn);
        this.gameinfo.appendChild(this.restart);
        this.score.style = "display: inline;padding: 20px;";
        var s1 = document.createTextNode("Score: ");
        this.score.appendChild(s1);
        this.gameinfo.appendChild(this.score);
        this.speed.style = "display: inline;padding: 20px;";
        var s2 = document.createTextNode("Speed: ");
        this.speed.appendChild(s2);
        this.gameinfo.appendChild(this.speed);
        this.high.style = "display: inline;padding: 20px;";
        var s3 = document.createTextNode("High Score: ");
        this.high.appendChild(s3);
        this.gameinfo.appendChild(this.high);
        this.scores.id = "score";
        var s1s = document.createTextNode("0");
        this.scores.appendChild(s1s);
        this.score.appendChild(this.scores);
        this.speeds.id = "speed";
        var s2s = document.createTextNode("2");
        this.speeds.appendChild(s2s);
        this.speed.appendChild(this.speeds);
        this.highs.id = "high";
        var s3s = document.createTextNode("0");
        this.highs.appendChild(s3s);
        this.high.appendChild(this.highs);
    }
}
myGameArea.start();
load();
restart();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Flappy Bird</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="game.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I have a 200 line fully functional flappy bird code but I was told it's suppose to be 250 lines.", why are the number of lines important?

Comment: it's for an assignment

Comment: Then the assignment is clearly flawed, it should be more about which features you as a developer should implement in the game. Could you provide a working version of your project in your question as a snippet please?

Comment: "I have a 200 line fully functional flappy bird code but I was told it's suppose to be 250 lines" What does the specification ask for, specifically? This question reads like you have information you're not telling us.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't anything specific, I wasn't told to add X so I don't have ideas on what to add in order to make my js 250 lines

Comment: "I have a 200 line fully functional flappy bird code but I was told it's suppose to be 250 lines." - Writing code is not like writing an essay. Having a "minimum" code length is a very strange requirement. Are you sure that's not a "maximum"? "...a pause button but I only know how to do it through css and not through JS" - How would add a _working_ pause button with CSS? What is the complication in adding a pause button (you seem to have already done the "hard" stuff)?

Comment: Some small ideas that can add complexity (and more lines): You could update the bird's physics to accelerate downwards. You could make the "flap" button do a quick spurt of upward accelaration, you could make spacebar and up also move the bird up, you could add audio, or animate a moving background in Javascript, etc.

Comment: Adding more lines is easy. Turn your `.style = "super long line of CSS"` into template literals with one property per line, move long `||`s into their own functions. That's something beneficial to do anyway. "Minimum lines" is a [very absurd requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184071/when-if-ever-is-number-of-lines-of-code-a-useful-metric) as others have pointed out.

Comment: Just use a more open style. VS will expand your code to 244 lines with the correct code format settings. Move all `var` to the top of their scope and you have 256 lines of code (no empty lines)